# ajax call its repeat append same data

Tags: php, ajax

I am making on scroll data load from mysql table using below code but on scroll it repeat some of data while loader running

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var lastID = $('.load-more').attr('lastID');
        if(($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) && (lastID != 0)){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'result_data.php',
                data:'id='+lastID,
                beforeSend:function(){
                    $('.load-more').show();   
                },
                success:function(response){
                    setTimeout(function() {
                    $('.load-more').remove();
                    $('#postList').append(response);
                }, 400);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Where `$('.load-more').attr('lastID')` is updated ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.after()` or `.insertAfter()`

The `.after()` and `.insertAfter()` methods perform the same task. The major difference is in the syntax—specifically, in the placement of the content and target. With `.after()`, the content to be inserted comes from the method's argument: `$(target).after(contentToBeInserted)`. With `.insertAfter()`, on the other hand, the content precedes the method and is inserted after the target, which in turn is passed as the `.insertAfter()` method's argument: `$(contentToBeInserted).insertAfter(target)`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var lastID = $('.load-more').attr('lastID');
        if(($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) && (lastID != 0)){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'result_data.php',
                data:'id='+lastID,
                beforeSend:function(){
                    $('.load-more').show();   
                },
                success:function(response){
                    setTimeout(function() {
                    $('.load-more').remove();
                    // $('#postList').append(response);
                    $('#postList').after(response);
                }, 400);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```